# Multidimensional scaling with periodic boundaries

Tags: data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, multidimensional-scaling

For a specific application at hand, I need to visualise samples from a high dimensional space into 2D, while respecting their distances as much as possible.

Normally, I would simply use Multidimensional Scaling, but in this application it is important that the boundaries of the 2D plane are periodic, forming a torus.

I have not come across any implementations of such a method, and in fact I have not even encountered theoretical work on it. Can you recommend either works on this topic, or provide an answer?

Comment: Can you add more explanation what you want, maybe a picture?